# Cross-reference sheets on Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I can just do `B12` to reference a field on the same sheet I'm working on, but how do I reference `B12` on another sheet?

Comment: Try asking on webapps.stackexchange.com (or wait until this question is closed and migrated there)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the same way as Excel would -

```
=SheetName!CellNumber
```

If your sheet name contains spaces, wrap the name in single quotes.

```
='Sheet Name'!CellNumber
```

Comment: I'd select you as the answer, but it won't let me since I just created my account here....

Comment: @Webnet drop in here ( http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7 ) & request @rchern for a merge in accounts :)

Comment: What if there's a space in the sheet name?

Comment: @Webnet wrap the name in single quotes. `='Sheet Name'!CellNumber`

Comment: What if I want to reference it by a formula?